# Python formatting string invalid syntax

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

In python 3.7, I have this very simple script. Why is this throwing a  invalid syntax error?

```
datestr = '2020-06-10'
print(f"C:/folder/{datestr.replace("-", "_")}/temp.csv")


 File "<ipython-input-38-95d22e47df04>", line 2
    print(f"C:/folder/{datestr.replace("-", "_")}/temp.csv")
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: print("C://folder//" + str(datestr).replace("-", "_") + "//temp.csv") why is your code inside a string??? Your code won't work inside a string.

Comment: @High-Octane It is an [f-string](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), so this will work once the problem with the string delimiters is fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to use `"` for different purposes in the same string.
You can interchange it with `'` to stop any confusion between string operations and terminating a string:

```
datestr = '2020-06-10'
print(f"C:/folder/{datestr.replace('-', '_')}/temp.csv")
```

Hope this helps!